# Javascript to replace all the input.value by '*' like a password typing

Tags: javascript

I have a

```
<input id="TxtBox" runat="server" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="">
```

And while doing the keypress, directly with js code, it replaces all the characters for '*'. Like a password typing.

**Edit: 2022**
As i read this old question i found imprecision why i wanted to avoid type="password" at that time. It was because if that attribute were in the tag the browser would remind a old password and it was annoying.

Edit:

I passed all day trying do put the **autocomplete=off** on all of my inputs to the browser stop asking password while someone is filling a form on my site, ddnt worked(a tried a few more things). And i thought in this type of solution i tried the javascript replace function but it only returned one char and decided to ask about a complete sequence of '*' while writing in a input. Tks for all the help.

sorry if i wasnt clear in the context i was just thinking in the code. i thought in some old i did before in C language but anyway i asked.

Edit:

I asked help how to do this in JS i did some stuff on keypress with JS functions like replace i did some code but i simply erased it and asked for some help. Next time i will post code to have some kick start code. I was doing something like

```
onkeypress="this.value=this.replace(this.value,'*')"
```

Tks in advance.

This is for in a visible input see a password typing and in a hidden i have it.

**note: i want to avoid type="password"**

Comment: `<input type=password>`?

Comment: im thinking in a way to do it without using type="password", tks for replying.

Comment: @TiagoT But why?

Comment: *im thinking in a way to do it without using type="password"* Then, you should edit your question to explain what it is that you are really trying to do.

Comment: You might also actually try to do this yourself, rather than making volunteers do your work for you...

Comment: ok ill do it tks all

Comment: *i want to tackle the keep password from browser with this* What does that mean? Please edit your question and be specific about what it is that you are trying to do, what you have tried and what you are stuck on.

Comment: See my updated answer for manual approach.

Comment: Why do you want it witout type password? I am just cerius to know your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need JavaScript to accomplish what HTML gives your for free? The element exposes all the same attributes/properties so you can still use it like a text box.

```html
<input type="password">
```

If you feel you must reinvent the wheel, this can be done by using two fields. The user will type in the first and it will display the mask character and the actual key will be stored in a hidden input field for processing:

```js
// Get references to DOM elements:
var txt = document.getElementById("txtMask");
var hdn = document.getElementById("pass");

// This keeps track of how many characters should be displayed
var maskLen = 1;

// Set up input event on first box
txt.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt){

  // Manually put the right amount of mask characters into the box
  // and update the maskLen value
  var str = '#'.repeat(maskLen++)
  this.value = str;
  
  // Cancel the event and stop bubbling
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  
  // Set the actual typed data into the hidden field
  hdn.value += evt.key;

  // Just for testing:
  console.clear();
  console.log("Actual data is: " + hdn.value);
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtMask" autocomplete="false">
<input type="hidden" id="pass">
```

Comment: He said I need to avoid input type password.

Comment: @M98 Answer was posted before he said that.

Comment: well thank you :) For what i see is a very complete code block for what i want. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `type="password"`

Like this:

```
<input type="password" id="TxtBox" runat="server" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="">
```

You can also do one of these:

```
input { -webkit-text-security: none; }
input { -webkit-text-security: circle; }
input { -webkit-text-security: square; }
input { -webkit-text-security: disc; /* Default */ }
```

You can use those without having a `type="password"`

Comment: Of course, any user-agent that doesn't respond to the `-webkit-` vendor prefix will show the characters.