# How to mask everything except last digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I am trying to mask everything except last digit using jquery mask but I am not able to get the logic to do it. Below is what I tried so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        onKeyPress: function(value, event, currentField, options) {
            var fieldVal = currentField.val();
            var star = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < fieldVal.length - 1; i++) {
                star += '*';
            }
            currentField.val(currentField.val().replace(/(.)(?!$)/g, star));
        }
    }
    $('.phone').mask('00000', options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="phone" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, what is exactly your issue? Because your example is masking all except the last one.

Comment: we cant type more the 2 digits. It should be till 5 digit

Comment: not able to type more than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to the applied `mask`, you are using `00000`, and a `0` only accepts a digit as input on that position. You will need to add a custom translation, as mentioned [here](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#translation), in the options.

For generate the new value of the input I will use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a custom [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to replace all characters by `*` except the last one.

## Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var options = {
        translation: {0: {pattern: /[0-9*]/}},
        onKeyPress: function(val, evt, currField, options)
        {
            let newVal = val.replace(/./g, (m, o, str) => (o !== str.length - 1 ? '*' : m));
            currField.val(newVal);
        }
    };

    $('.phone').mask('00000', options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="phone" />
</div>
```

Comment: if we unmask will we I get the actual entered value ?

Comment: No, you will have to create a logic for storing the original value somewhere.

Comment: can you give a javascript version of it ?

Comment: @SusheelSingh Sorry for delay to answer, I had a hard day at work, you can try the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074827/javascript-to-replace-all-the-input-value-by-like-a-password-typing that uses a hidden input. However, take note you will need to do something with special keys like `backspace`. Take the example as a base reference.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to use simple `regex` here, no need for `jquery.mask`.

```js
$("input[name='phone']").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d\*]/g, '').replace(/\d(?=\d{1})/g,'*'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="phone" name="phone" />
</div>
```